# Implementing collision response, current implementation does too many checks

Tags: c++, collision, sfml

I don't know how I should handle my collision response when collision between two entities leads to second collision with third entity.

*Blue arrow is velocity of the rightmost entity and numbers below are single collision response.*

**Single Collision**

[image]

At the beginning leftmost and middle entities are not colliding with each others, but after rightmost entity collides with middle one, the velocity middle entity gains now causes it to collide with leftmost one

**How end result should be**

[image]
*Or if the leftmost entity was a wall -> 0, 0, -v*

**Current implementation:** check collisions until all are handled

[image]

Velocities before collision handling

- 0, 0, <-10
- Collisions: 2&3

*If entity velocity is changed due the collision do new check*

After 1. collision check:

- 0, <-5, <-5
- Collisions: 1&2

After 2. collision check:

- <-2.5, <-2.5, <-5
- Collisions: 2&3

After 3. collision check:

- <-2.5, <-3.75, <-3.75
- Collisions: 1&2

After 4. collision check:

- <-3.125, <-3.125, <-3.75
- Collisions: 2&3

After nth collision check:

- <-3.33, <-3.33, <-3.33
- No collisions
- Continue

**Question:** As we clearly see, it takes way too many collision checks to fix even simple collisions this way. How should I improve this?

**Sample code written with sfml:**

I have 3 types of entities in my test case:

- wall
- pushable
- passable

*Entity, velocity and boundingRect:*

[image]

*Collision response:*

[image]

- wall <-> pushable: can't move inside wall, push pushable entity away
- pushable <-> pushable: both are repelled from each others so they won't collide
- wall<->wall: skip collision checks between walls and all checks with passable terrain

Controls in sample code

- Arrow keys: move green entity
- Left mouse button: spawn pushable entities
- Right mouse button: spawn wall entities
- Middle mouse button: spawn moving pushable entities

.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

const sf::Vector2f entitySize(16.f, 16.f);

bool isMovingUp = false;
bool isMovingDown = false;
bool isMovingRight = false;
bool isMovingLeft = false;

enum Category
{
    wall,
    pushable,
    passable,
};

class Entity
{
    public:
        Entity(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Color color, Category type) : position(position), type(type)
        {
            shape.setSize(entitySize);
            shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
            shape.setOutlineColor(color);
            shape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
        }

        sf::Vector2f position;
        sf::Vector2f velocity;
        sf::Vector2f adjustedVelocity;
        sf::Vector2f defaultVelocity;
        sf::RectangleShape shape;
        Category type;
};

void DrawEntity(sf::RenderWindow& window, Entity& entity)
{
    entity.shape.setPosition(entity.position - entity.shape.getSize() / 2.f);
    window.draw(entity.shape);
}

sf::FloatRect GetBoundingRect(const Entity& entity)
{
    return sf::FloatRect(entity.position+entity.velocity - entitySize / 2.f, entitySize);
}

void HandleCollision(std::vector<Entity>& entities)
{
    bool allCollisionsChecked = false;

    while(!allCollisionsChecked)
    {
        allCollisionsChecked = true;

        // Pair all possible combinations, but only once per pair
        for (auto first = entities.begin(); first != entities.end(); ++first)
        {
            for (auto second = std::next(first); second != entities.end(); ++second)
            {
                if (first->type == Category::passable || second->type == Category::passable || first->type == Category::wall && second->type == Category::wall)
                    continue;

                sf::FloatRect intersection;
                if (GetBoundingRect(*first).intersects(GetBoundingRect(*second), intersection))
                {
                    if (second->position == first->position)
                        second->position.x += entitySize.x;

                    sf::Vector2f direction = second->position - first->position;
                    sf::Vector2f offset;

                    // X collision
                    if (abs(direction.x) > abs(direction.y))
                        offset.x = ((direction.x<0)?-1:1)*intersection.width;

                    // Y collision
                    if (abs(direction.x) < abs(direction.y))
                        offset.y = ((direction.y<0)?-1:1)*intersection.height;

                    if(first->type == Category::pushable && second->type == Category::pushable)
                    {
                        first->velocity -= offset / 2.f;
                        second->velocity += offset / 2.f;
                        allCollisionsChecked = false;
                    }
                    else if(first->type == Category::pushable)
                    {
                        first->velocity -= offset;
                        allCollisionsChecked = false;
                    }
                    else if(second->type == Category::pushable)
                    {
                        second->velocity += offset;
                        allCollisionsChecked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case sf::Keyboard::Up:
        isMovingUp = isPressed;
        break;
    case sf::Keyboard::Down:
        isMovingDown = isPressed;
        break;
    case sf::Keyboard::Left:
        isMovingLeft = isPressed;
        break;
    case sf::Keyboard::Right:
        isMovingRight = isPressed;
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML Application");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    std::vector<Entity> entities;

    Entity player(sf::Vector2f(1280/2, 720/2), sf::Color::Green, Category::pushable);
    entities.push_back(player);

    size_t cols = 1280/int(entitySize.x);
    size_t rows = 720/int(entitySize.y);

    for (size_t i=0; i < cols*rows; ++i)
        if (i%cols == rows/5 && i/cols > rows/6 && i/cols < rows*5/6 || i%cols >= rows/5 && i%cols <= rows*4/5 && (i/cols == rows/6 || i/cols == rows*5/6))
            entities.push_back(Entity(sf::Vector2f(entitySize.x*(i%cols)+entitySize.x/2, entitySize.y*(i/cols)+entitySize.y/2), sf::Color::Yellow, Category::wall));
        //else
            //entities.push_back(Entity(sf::Vector2f(entitySize.x*(i%cols)+entitySize.x/2, entitySize.y*(i/cols)+entitySize.y/2), sf::Color::Transparent, Category::passable));

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                sf::Vector2i pixel(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y);
                sf::Vector2f coord = window.mapPixelToCoords(pixel);

                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    Entity pushable(coord, sf::Color::Blue, Category::pushable);
                    entities.push_back(pushable);
                }
                else if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    Entity wall(coord, sf::Color::Yellow, Category::wall);
                    entities.push_back(wall);
                }
                else if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Middle)
                {
                    Entity mover(coord, sf::Color::Magenta, Category::pushable);
                    mover.defaultVelocity.x = -1.f;
                    entities.push_back(mover);
                }
            }

            switch (event.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, true);
                    break;

                case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                    handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, false);
                    break;

                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (isMovingUp)
            entities[0].velocity.y -= 5.f;
        if (isMovingDown)
            entities[0].velocity.y += 5.f;
        if (isMovingLeft)
            entities[0].velocity.x -= 5.f;
        if (isMovingRight)
            entities[0].velocity.x += 5.f;

        if (entities[0].velocity.x != 0.f && entities[0].velocity.y != 0.f)
        {
            entities[0].velocity.x /= std::sqrt(2.f);
            entities[0].velocity.y /= std::sqrt(2.f);
        }

        HandleCollision(entities);

        // Apply and reset velocities
        for (Entity& e : entities)
        {
            e.position += e.velocity;
            e.velocity = e.defaultVelocity;
        }

        // Draw
        window.clear();
        for (Entity& e : entities)
            DrawEntity(window, e);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

**Sample results**

Magenta entities are moving to the left with constant speed and yellow entities are wall.

*without checking collisions due the other collisions*

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

*Same scenario when checking collisions until all are resolved*

How could I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: This is a very rich topic with maaaany options.  I have multiple books that dedicate chapters to the tradeoffs here.  In the end, it comes down to complexity vs. accuracy vs. predictability of code execution time.  For example, are you allowed variable time steps?  Are you allowed to fudge accuracy a little by letting objects overlap slightly?  Can you let some of the collisions that techically were in this time quanta happen in the next because the time steps are tiny enough?  How accurately do you need to simulate something like "Newton's Cradle"?

Comment: In my actual implementation I use variable timesteps and I don't really need very accurate physics. I simply want to prevent entities from moving or pushing each others through walls or other entities, while still allowing them to push other pushable entities around.